# Getting the value of both inputs and a select menu

Tags: reactjs

How can I capture (and set in the state) the value of both the inputs and the select with the same handleChange method? This code won´t work, since select doesn´t have a name property to it.

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      age: '',
      name: '',
      selected: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange (evt) {
    this.setState({ [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value });
  }

  render () {
const unique = [...new Set(props.items.map(item => item.position))];
       const items = unique.map((i, index) =>{return ( <option onChange={this.handleChange} value={i} key={index}> {i}</option> )
      });
   return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" 
          pattern= "/[a-zA-Z]+" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input type="number" name="age" 
         min="18" max="40" onChange={this.handleChange} />
 <React.Fragment>
  <select>{items}</select>
 </React.Fragment>
       <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Search</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store the value from a select tag into the store, use a separate `handleChange` method (e.g. `handleSelectChange`) and pass that method to the select component.

Alternatively, if you wanted to use the same method, you could use a switch statement:

```
handleChange (evt) {
    switch(evt.target.type) {
      case 'input':
        this.setState({ [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value });
        break;
      case 'select':
        this.setState({ selected: evt.target.value });
        break;
    }

  }
```

There's a great example of how to store the value from a select component in the React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag

Comment: I am using one for the inputs already. I want to know if there´s a way to use the same method for both the inputs and the select menu.

Comment: I've edited my answer to be more clear. You can either create a separate method just for the select, or you can use a switch statement with the event handler (`evt.target.type`) to determine whether it came from an `input />` or a `<select />`